# How to add a description for slash command arguments in nextcord?

Tags: discord, nextcord

I've been trying to add a description for my slash command arguments in nextcord, I can't seem to firgure out how.

This is my code:

```
@__Bot__.slash_command(description="Retrieve a Quran verse.")
async def hello(interaction: nextcord.Interaction, start: str, verse: str, end: Optional[int]):
    VerseCommand = [(start, verse, end)]
....
```

[This is what I am hoping to achieve. "Page Number"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hiwHw.png)

I tried using `from nextcord import Options` but it doesn't work.

Comment: Please do not include the discord.py tag if you are using a fork of discord.py

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple ways to achieve this.

### Option 1 - [`SlashOption`](https://docs.nextcord.dev/en/stable/api.html#nextcord.SlashOption)

You can add additional settings for slash command options including the description, choices, and value ranges by setting a default value using the `SlashOption` class. See the [Application Command Docs](https://docs.nextcord.dev/en/stable/interactions.html) and more [examples](https://github.com/nextcord/nextcord/tree/master/examples/application_commands).

```py
@__Bot__.slash_command(description="Retrieve a Quran verse.")
async def hello(
    interaction: nextcord.Interaction,
    start: str = nextcord.SlashOption(description="Enter Start")
    verse: str = nextcord.SlashOption(description="Enter Verse"),
    end: Optional[int] = nextcord.SlashOption(description="Enter End"),
):
    VerseCommand = [(start, verse, end)]
```

### Option 2 - Numpy-style, Google-style, or Sphinx-style docstrings

You can find examples of each supported style in [PR 480](https://github.com/nextcord/nextcord/pull/480).

Example using Google-style docstrings (replace "Enter start value", "Enter verse value", etc with your descriptions)

```py
@__Bot__.slash_command(description="Retrieve a Quran verse.")
async def hello(interaction: nextcord.Interaction, start: str, verse: str, end: Optional[int]):
    """
    Your command description goes here

    Args:
        interaction: The interaction object
        start: Enter start value
        verse: Enter verse value
        end: Enter end value
    """
    VerseCommand = [(start, verse, end)]
```

Example using Numpy-style docstrings:

```py
@__Bot__.slash_command(description="Retrieve a Quran verse.")
async def hello(interaction: nextcord.Interaction, start: str, verse: str, end: Optional[int]):
    """
    Your command description goes here

    Parameters
    ----------
    interaction:
        The interaction object
    start:
        Enter start value
    verse:
        Enter verse value
    end:
        Enter end value
    """
    VerseCommand = [(start, verse, end)]
```

Example using Sphinx-style docstrings:

```py
@__Bot__.slash_command(description="Retrieve a Quran verse.")
async def hello(interaction: nextcord.Interaction, start: str, verse: str, end: Optional[int]):
    """
    Your command description goes here

    :param interaction: The interaction object
    :param start: Enter start value
    :param verse: Enter verse value
    :param end: Enter end value
    """
    VerseCommand = [(start, verse, end)]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the double quotes to add a description to each argument:

```py
@__Bot__.slash_command(description="Retrieve a Quran verse.")
async def hello(interaction: nextcord.Interaction, start: str, verse: str, end: Optional[int]):
    """
    Parameters
    ----------
    interaction: Interaction
    start: str
        description1
    verse: str
        description2
    end: str
        description3
    """
    VerseCommand = [(start, verse, end)]
```

Comment: I don't understand what you mean, how am I exactly supposed to input this into the code? Would be appreciated if you could elaborate.

Comment: you can put the description like i did inside the double quotes nextcord will automatically use the description for the parameters

Answer (score 0):

I just did this for my bot. Your example appears to be from a different slash_command because I don't see `page` as an argument anywhere in your code. Nevertheless, this works straight from the nextcord documentation.

```
@bot.slash_command(guild_ids=[TESTING_GUILD_ID])
async def hi(interaction: nextcord.Interaction, user: nextcord.Member):
    """Say hi to a user

    Parameters
    ----------
    interaction: Interaction
        The interaction object
    user: nextcord.Member
        The user to say hi to.
    """
    await interaction.response.send_message(
        f"{interaction.user} just said hi to {user.mention}"
    )
```

Reference: https://docs.nextcord.dev/en/stable/interactions.html#slash-command-options